# Create a .txt with Password

Tags: c#, file, passwords

I write a program that create a file .txt in my Desktop. Now I want the file created has a password to read.

How to create a .txt with a password?

Comment: There is no such thing as a password protected file by default. You could encrypt your file with a password so it's unreadable to the normal guy with notepad, but you would need to write an application that decrypts it, too.

Comment: Have you **ever** seen a txt with password? If no one else has done it, why do you think it can be done?

Comment: @xanatos Technically .txt is more of a loose standard regarding encoding, file ending etc. So as long as the OP is willing to run his own data-format and his own viewers he could implement a badly done password protection/encryption scheme. It's not a good idea, but it can be done :P

Comment: @fk2 It wouldn't be a .txt file. It would be a file. A .txt file is something that can be read by Notepad++. Now... There is probably no RFC for .txt, but saying "it can be anything, including a binary file" is probably a little too much.

Comment: You can change file name to PasswordProtectedFile.txt. Lame, I know that,

Comment: @xanatos yeah, I guess I'm indeed straining to see meaning in the OP's question here.

Comment: @FaisalHafeez *drum snare*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try compressing it with 7zip and giving it a password while creating the archive.